# Map of React Components not re rendering on State Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Setup where i have a map of React Components which needs to shown in view.

Also there are many input select handlers which update the parent component state but after the state update the Parent Component render method is called but the Child Component doesn't refresh the Values .

What am i missing here ? I am bit confused

A minimal Reproduction of the Problem [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qa6s46).

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

export const ReactExample = ({ name, value, handleChange }) => (
  <select name={name} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
    <option value="A">Apple</option>
    <option value="B">Banana</option>
    <option value="C">Cranberry</option>
  </select>
)

const Section = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.header}
      <br />
      {props.primaryNode}
      <br />
      {props.bottom}
    </div>
  );
};


class App extends React.PureComponent {

  state = {
    current: 'B'
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  show = [5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 8, 77, 8, 90];

  primaryNode = () => {
    const filterData = this.show;

    return (<div>{filterData}----{this.state.current} // doesn't get updated even though state updates after dropdown</div>);
  };

  bottom = () => {
    return (
      <ReactExample name="fruit" value={this.state.current} handleChange={this.handleChange} />

    )
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value); // always logged and state updated with no change in value
    this.setState({ current: event.target.value });
  }

  data = ["A", "B", "C"];

  map = {
    "A": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} bottom={this.bottom()} header={"A"} />),
    "B": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"B"} />),
    "C": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"C"} />)
  };

  render() {
    return (<div>{this.data.map(d => this.map[d])}</div>)
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class field `map` is initialized only **once**, at first component render. It does not really matter that you change the state, that variable holds the very same data and does not change in time.

One of the solutions would be moving that variable into render:

```
render() {
    const map = {
        "A": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} bottom={this.bottom()} header={"A"} />),
        "B": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"B"} />),
        "C": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"C"} />)
    };

    return (<div>{this.data.map(d => this.map[d])}</div>)
}
```

or you could transform `map` field into a method:

```
map = () => ({
    "A": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} bottom={this.bottom()} header={"A"} />),
    "B": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"B"} />),
    "C": (<Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"C"} />)
});

render() {
    return (<div>{this.data.map(d => this.map()[d])}</div>)
}
```

So the data returned by `map` is always up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks everyone its was silly mistake and i feel that is the reason you should not work late nights some times mind fails to register. And next time i will restrain from posting on SO till next day. :)
I really liked the approach you gave me you options even for a fault of mine

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making this more confusing than it needs to be by holding all these values as class properties. The reason that they are not updating is because `this.map` is only defined once. You don't need map at all, just render your nodes directly inside `render` function which gets called on state changes:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} bottom={this.bottom()} header={"A"} />
      <Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"B"} />
      <Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"C"} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And if you really want it to be a map, then define it inside `render`:

```
render() {
  const map = {
    "A": <Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} bottom={this.bottom()} header={"A"} />,
    "B": <Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"B"} />,
    "C": <Section primaryNode={this.primaryNode()} header={"C"} />
  };

  return <div>{this.data.map(d => map[d])}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone its was silly mistake and i feel that is the reason you should not work late nights some times mind fails to register. And next time i will restrain from posting on SO till next day. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're wanting to do, but it sounds like you want your A/B/C values to be updated with state-change. The problem is that you are defining the primaryNode in your map-object *before* `render()`, rather than *inside* of `render()` (which always re-renders when state changes. Try this:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

const Section = item => (
  <>
    <br/>
    <section>
      {item.header}
      <br />
      {item.primaryNode}
      <br />
      {item.bottom}
    </section>
  </>
);

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    current: 'B'
  }

  data = ["A", "B", "C"];
  show = [5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 8, 77, 8, 90];

  bottom = () => (
    <select name={"fruit"} value={this.state.current} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <option value="A">Apple</option>
      <option value="B">Banana</option>
      <option value="C">Cranberry</option>
    </select>
  );

  handleChange = (event) => (
    this.setState({ current: event.target.value })
  );

  primaryNode = () => (
    <div className="primary-node">
      {this.show} ---- {this.state.current}
    </div>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        State Value - {this.state.current}
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        {this.data.map(el => (
          <Section 
            bottom={el === "A" && this.bottom()}
            header={el}
            primaryNode={this.primaryNode()}
          />
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks everyone its was silly mistake and i feel that is the reason you should not work late nights some times mind fails to register. And next time i will restrain from posting on SO till next day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `map` inside the `render()` method.
`render()` is fired when the state changes so it's the place You're looking for

Comment: Thanks everyone its was silly mistake and i feel that is the reason you should not work late nights some times mind fails to register. And next time i will restrain from posting on SO till next day. :)